# How do I catch 'critters'?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

Numerous in-game sources (NPCs, item descriptions, etc.) have made reference to how combining items with 'critters' can yield elixirs with a variety of effects. That sounds really neat.

The only problem is - I don't have any idea how to gather these 'critters'. I've noticed several types of animals, but none of them that I can seemingly just waltz up to. In previous Zelda games, you needed special items to interact with certain critters, but I've found no mention of that so far.

How do I capture confoundingly mobile elixir ingredients?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're fast, you can run up to frogs near some ponds and catch them on the go. That's also possible with lizards, but a lot more difficult.

But you're right, you can't simply waltz up to most critters as you'll scare them off. You need to sneak up to them slowly. Crouching helps, as does moving slowly. Remember that you have a sound meter that shows you how much noise you're making. Make sure to keep an eye on it and keep the line as flat as possible and you should be able to sneak up to bugs and catch them. You can easily catch 3-4 fireflies at night simply be crouching around them.

The noise meter is the purple line in the bottom right corner. The more erratic it is, the more noise you're making. Handy for sneaking up on enemies too.

[image: Breath of the Wild HUD showing mini-map, temperature meter and noise meter]

Comment: Interesting - so I DON'T need anything special to catch bugs? I had noticed I could catch fish just by swimming up to them, but previous Zeldas have typically had bug nets...

Comment: @twobugs As far as I can tell, you don't need a net. Like I said, I've caught a couple of crickets, I managed to snag a lizard which I think counts as a critter, and I missed a couple of prompt for fireflies, but the prompt was there. I suppose it's possible other critters need a net that I haven't found yet, but it seems unlikely to me.

Comment: And with the full set of stealth armor equipped, you can walk up to almost anything (and not sprinting).  I usually would find the bugs flying away from me standing on them long before I notice them.

Comment: You are right! I previously sneaked up to a Sneaky River Snail (being really careful not to scare it off) and I managed to snatch it away. ;D Jokes aside, only fireflies, bugs, frogs and such are really hard to catch. There are critters like crabs and snails that are pretty easy.

Answer (score 7):

My way of getting critters is that I've fully upgraded the Sheikah armor set, which gives a lot of stealth and movement speed at night. I can run straight up to a critter and it won't move for a second or so, giving me plenty of time to grab it.

Comment: This is my preferred method as well. Just running around with my finger on the <kbd>A</kbd> button I catch so many bugs and fish!

Comment: You can walk at full speed right up to a critter -- I find they usually still hear me if I _run_.

Answer (score 3):

Critters are frogs and lizards and bugs/insects. You can catch these easily by shooting them with a bow and arrow, then you do not even need to sneak. Just be on the look out for them. Frogs are near ponds and lizards hang out on tree trunks. Frogs are generally the easiest to catch.

Answer (score 2):

Sneaking, particularly with the Sheikah set, is the best method. But you can also find a lot of critters (lizards and insects usually) under rocks too, so I usually pick up rocks when I'm wandering around.
You have to be pretty quick to press A to grab them before they run off though.

You can often catch some as you are running around too, but again you have to always be prepared to tap A as soon as the prompt appears on the screen. It can be tricky to get things this way, but I have caught quite a few with out specifically hunting for them this way.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to the Sheikah set and naturally sneaking is cooking food with stealth ingredients such as Silent Princess, Silent Shroom, Sneaky River Snail, or Blue Nightshade will naturally decrease the amount of noise you create making it easier to catch critters while walking or even running. Keeping your thumb near the A button will also help so you can catch the critter as soon as the option appears.